# C++ Написать программу «Подсчет единичных островов». Заполнить двухмерный массив 12х12 0 и 1

Tags: c++, алгоритм

0 – это вода, 1 – это земля. Воды должно быть в три раза больше, чем земли. Необходимо посчитать количество единичных островов. Единичным островом считается 1, окруженная со всех сторон 0.

```
11000
00010
10000
```

Примечание: единичный остров, стоящий на углу, не будет окружен водой со всех сторон, учтите это при проверке, чтобы не выйти за пределы массива.

Помогите пожалуйста. Я вообще не представляю как их подсчитать.

Вот начало вроде положено:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
srand(time(0)); 
rand();
const int n = 12;
int mas[n][n] = {};
int x, y, kol_vo = 0;

while (kol_vo < 36)
{
x = rand() % n;
y = rand() % n;
if (mas[x][y] == 0)
{
mas[x][y] = 1;
kol_vo++;
}
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Знаете, при таком количестве - обычным тривиальным перебором...

Comment: Я помню, по крайней мере, две темы на этом сайте с аналогичной темой. В одной я сам отвечал. Так что ищите, да обрящете.

Comment: Если б нашел, то не спрашивал бы. Я пока что плохо в этом смыслю. И для меня подобное (если коды выполняют те же функции, но выглядят совсем иначе, то что мы еще не проходили) может крайне отличаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

лобовым алгоритмом довольно просто:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int f(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& m)
{
    int c = 0;
    bool b = false;    
    for (size_t i = 1; i < m.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 1; j < m[0].size()-1; ++j)
        {
            if (m[i][j])
            {
                b = m[i-1][j-1] | m[i-1][j] | m[i-1][j+1]
                  | m[i][j-1]   | m[i][j+1] 
                  | m[i+1][j-1] | m[i+1][j] | m[i+1][j+1];
                c += !b;
            }
        }
    }

    return c;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m = {       
        {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };    
    std::cout << f(m);    
    return 0;
}
```

по сути это тупая проверка всех соседей единичного элемента матрицы на `0`.

А подсчёт кол-ва в переменной `c`.

В целях оптимизации специально убрал лишние условные операторы `if`

Будут вопросы задавайте

Comment: @BenX пожалуйста, и не забудьте нажать на галочку приняв мой ответ

Comment: Ок. Я тут впервые. Спасибо=) Про вектор кстати еще незнал, т.к. не проходили. И m.size() - что-то новенькое, поэтому обошелся тем, что мне более менее известно.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось! Спасибо @ampawd! Я использовал часть вашего кода и вот, что вышло:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
const int n = 12;
int f(int mas[n][n])
{
    int c = 0;
    bool b = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
    for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; ++j)
    {
        if (mas[i][j])
        {
            b = mas[i - 1][j - 1] | mas[i - 1][j] | mas[i - 1][j + 1]
              | mas[i][j - 1]     | mas[i][j + 1]
              | mas[i + 1][j - 1] | mas[i + 1][j] | mas[i + 1][j + 1];
                c += !b;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
void main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    rand();

    int mas[n][n] = {};
    int x, y, kol_vo = 0;

    while (kol_vo < 36)
    {
        x = rand() % n;
        y = rand() % n;
        if (mas[x][y] == 0)
        {
            mas[x][y] = 1;
            kol_vo++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout <<"Ostrovkov = "<<f(mas)<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```